# Creating a second header navigation menu in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I would like to create a second navigation menu that goes below the main one (The one that contains the "About" and "Contact" etc. categories). This one would have images that have links and also which show text under them when hovered on. I have already created the necessary HTML and CSS for it, I just don't know how I would implement that into my site. The images and links are in a table, but the Wordpress navigation menu is a list, so I'm kind of stuck on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a default/premium/free theme, or did you create one by yourself?
I assume the first, so here are a few things you need to know.

- Wordpress uses hooks, so you can "link" your code at a certain point of their code, when a website is called. In its codex, you can [learn more about how navigation menus are registered and called later on.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus)
- A theme is something like a base, when you create your own website. You can create [child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and implement every further functionality and design changes 
  right there.

In short: implement your menu, put it in your child theme and use the hooks to get it where you need.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I do have a child theme. Basically what I want to do, is make that nav menu space accommodate the table I created that would act as a sort of nav menu. Is that possible with the hooks you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Standard way of adding a secondary menu to a theme is as follows.

```
register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'yourtheme'),
        'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu', 'yourtheme' ),
     ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the question I was trying to ask is where do I put my HTML code of the table so that it shows up on the header, but I found the solution through sheer luck. I put the HTML into the header.php of my child theme and linked the CSS classes to those that I pasted into the style.css . Still, thanks to those who tried to answer!